# Loading a Page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function in a floatbox like this:

```
parent.fb.resize( {left: -360, width: true, height:true }, function () {
    parent.location.reload( true );
}, 0.7 );
```

Ignore the fb.resize which is part of Floatbox. It's the callback function

```
parent.location.reload( true );
```

which I'm trying to improve upon. The function reloads the parent page from the server, and a PHP session variable controls the content of the parent page.

The problem I have is that the address bar only shows www.mywebsite.com/ so the user can't copy it as a link. Instead I would like it to show www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php?parameter=something. So I need the callback function to send the parameter with a GET, instead of relying on the seesion variable/ But, how?

Comment: find click or navigation events and make use of history.pushState({t: new Date().getTime()}, "page something", "/mypage.php?parameter=something");  check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the way num8er suggested. The callback function became

```
parent.window.history.pushState(null, null, "mypage.php?parameter=<?php echo $_SESSION['something'] ?>");
parent.location.reload( true );
```

Then because there are times when the session parameter has not been set, I expanded it to

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['something'])) { ?>
parent.window.history.pushState(null, null, "mypage.php?parameter=<?php echo $_SESSION['something'] ?>");
parent.location.reload( true );
<?php }else{?>
parent.location.replace( "http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php" );
<?php }?>
```